# Webkit border colour text colour bug

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

I have some HTML emulating the Mac OS X dock app context menu, and have run into a problem in both Chrome and Safari.

Have a look at this example here (http://jsfiddle.net/HenXL/1/) in both Chrome and then Firefox. In Chrome, for some reason the text colour of the siblings elements to the hr element become the same colour as the hr elements border colour.

[image: Firefox on the left vs Chrome on the right]

I am not sure why this is happening, I may have made an obvious mistake (it is late) but I cannot see a problem with the code.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, or shed any light on the situation?

Comment: They both look fine to me on Windows Firefox 6 and Chrome 13. No difference in colour.

Comment: So are you seeing full white text in Chrome 13 like the image on the left? Because I see the grey version on the right of the attached image.

Comment: Yup. Full white text in *both* browsers. Maybe it is Mac related.

Comment: Yer looks like Boris Smus confirms that its a Mac problem.

Comment: I can confirm that it looks fine on Chrome 13 for Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with the current stable version of Chrome (13), at least on Mac. Strangely, if you select the text, it changes color to become white as it should.

It seems to be fixed in 14 onward.

This is being caused by border: transparent; in your .content hr rule. Here it is, removed: http://jsfiddle.net/AJfcQ/

Could be related to this issue: http://crbug.com/68371